# Hide a column in bootstrapTable using javascript or jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, bootstrap-table

I'm using bootStrap Table for my users using below example.

http://www.redexperu.com/assets/js/bootstrap-table-master/docs/examples.html#via-javascript-table

I want to hide Edit and delete options by hiding in **operate** (Here Delete User Column) data field in the table. I was trying to do it by using below command

```
$('#table').bootstrapTable('hideColumn', 'operate');
```

by refering this

https://github.com/wenzhixin/bootstrap-table-examples/blob/master/methods/showColumn-hideCoulumn.html

It doesn't seems to work. 
Here is my sample code. This is not complete one. I added here only parts I thought necessary.

https://jsfiddle.net/Menuka/ht3dwwt9/4/

My table works fine but not the column hiding part.

Comment: code is perfect, where is issue? also put your full html and jquery for reference.

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/Menuka/jw9ghk4v/1/

Comment: Above is full jsp and js code.

Comment: @Bharat The show columns and hide columns are work fine when it wrote to button click. but not in **$(document).ready(function(){** without any click events

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As Bharat mentioned in his comment, my code works fine. But the problem is when **hidecolumn** and **showcolumn** are executing, the table is not loaded. So those commands run uselessly. One way to avoid these kind of situations is to bind it with event like **.click()**. In my case it is not the solution. After a while I find out this **setTimeout** method. So I used it to solve my problem like below.

```
<script>
 setTimeout(function(){ $('#table').bootstrapTable('showColumn', 'operate2'); }, 100);
</script>
```

you can find out about **setTimeout** method referring this. 
http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/met_win_settimeout.asp

Hope someone find this useful. Any other solutions are welcome.

Answer (score 0):

You can set visibility at the initial rendering of the bootstrap table, add visible:false to the column you want to hide.

```
$('#tableContainerName').bootstrapTable('destroy').bootstrapTable({
        url: YourApiUrl,
        pagination: true,
        search: true,
        columns: [{
                field: 'ColumnName',
                title: 'ColumnTitle',
                visible:false
            }]
    });
```